# How can i get current product link on prestashop custom blocks?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to create a WhatsApp button in prestashop. It should send the link of the current product to WhatsApp.

For this I have written some code in a custom block:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=905xxxxx&text= <?php {$urls.current_url} ?>">
```

But `<?php {$urls.current_url} ?>` this section display as a text on web browser.

How can I get current product link on prestashop custom blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the PHP tag in the TPL files.

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=905xxxxx&text={$urls.current_url}">
```

You can also get different parts of the URL through this command: "$smarty.get"

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my html which works...

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=" onclick="window.open('whatsapp://send?text=%20%2ALook%20what%20I%20found%20on%20PP%2A%20-%20' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;">
     <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="color: #7a7a7a;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on WhatsApp"></i> {* WHATSAPP COLOR #25D366 *}
</a>
```